# List WordPress Categories with Ajax in Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress

I have more than 14000 categories in WordPress, when I click on All Posts, the page is super slow because it loads 28000 lines of code (page source) categories in it, and it becomes impossible to do any task, the same happens when I try to edit/create any post.

Is there any plugin which loads list of categories with Ajax, instead of hard-coded list of all 14000 categories while editing/creating a post ? I tried to search for this solution but didn't find anything, I tried to disable categories but it simply removed from the View, but in fact those are in page source with same effect.

Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a public repo you can use on github, but most likely will have to implement a small custom plugin probably 3 or 4 files. Here is what I would write to get started  `example-plugin.php`

```php
/**
 * example function
 */
function product_display() {

    /* Create drop down */
    $criteria = array(
        'parent' => 0, // only direct child from category 0 (top parent)
        'hide_empty' => 0, // show category even when there is no post
        'exclude' => 1, //  exclude category with id 0 (uncategorized)
        'echo' => 0, // throw output to variable
        'show_option_none' => __('None'),
        'name' => 'selectcat1' // select form name
    );
    echo wp_dropdown_categories($criteria);

    echo "<div id='product_container'></div>";

}

function product_get_category() {
    global $wpdb; // access the database
    $cat_id = intval($_POST['cat_id']);
    $form_name = 'selectcat'.$cat_id;
    
    if (category_has_children($cat_id)) {
        $cat_criteria = array(
            'parent' => $cat_id, 
            'hide_empty' => 0, 
            'exclude' => 1, 
            'echo' => 0, 
            'show_option_none' => __('None'),
            'name' => $form_name 
        );
        echo wp_dropdown_categories($cat_criteria); 
    } else {
        $post_criteria = array(
            'cat' => $cat_id,
            'post_type' => 'product'
        );
}

/* create ajax call product_get_content */
add_action('wp_ajax_product_get_content', 'product_get_content');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_product_get_content', 'product_get_content');
```

Then make a `script.js` file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('change', "[id^=selectcat]", function() {    
        var cat_id = $(this).children(':selected').attr('value');
        var form_id = this.id;

        var data = {
            action: 'product_get_category',
            cat_id: cat_id
        };      

        jQuery.post(categoryAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('#'+form_id).nextAll("[id^=selectcat]").remove(); 
            $('#'+form_id).nextAll("[id=content_product]").remove(); 
            $('#product_container').replaceWith('<div id="product_container"></id>'); 
            $(response).insertAfter($('#'+form_id));
        });
    }):
```

obviously, this isn't the whole plugin and you will have to do some custom styling for the admin dashboard etc. But this should give an idea of how to solve this issue.